# Pasar queue por referencia a funcion

Tags: c++

Quiero pasar por referencia un `Queue` de tipo `string` que he creado para guardar nombres, para mostrarlos por pantalla estos deben ser pasados por referencia ya que no quiero tener todo en el `main` y este objeto en el futuro debe ser manipulado en otras funciones.

```
queue<string>datos;
datos.push("Albert");
datos.push("Maria");
datos.push("Juan");
```

Algo como;

```
void listar( queue datos) {
//Codigo...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las referencias sirven para definir "alias" para un mismo objeto de esta manera interactuamos y manipulamos un objeto `a` en las funciones necesarias y todas las acciones afectaran al mismo objeto `a`. Para ello se usa el operador de referencia (&).

```
void listar( queue<string>& queue_data) {

    while(!queue_data.empty()) {
        cout<<" -> " <<queue_data.front() <<endl;
        queue_data.pop();
    }
}
```

La salida seria;

```
Juan
Maria
Albert
```